# MySQL count consecutive days / days in a row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have two tables. Both contain entries of one user, one from the morning, one from the evening.

I am trying to get the amount of days, that the user consequently added one entry in the morning AND one in the evening. Whenever there is one missing, the "streak" ends - ending at the current day. So it doesn't mind if the user was active a year ago and had 100 days in a row, it's just "how many days in a row did the user add an entry in the morningTable, as well as in the eveningTable, going back from today".

Both tables have timestamps of every entry.

An example:

```
morningTable:

ID text timestamp
1  bla  2020-08-07 10:30:00
2  blub 2020-08-06 11:30:00
3  abc  2020-08-05 09:20:00
4  def  2020-08-04 06:13:00
5  ghi  2020-08-02 07:05:00

eveningTable:

ID text timestamp
1  abc  2020-08-07 19:30:00
2  def  2020-08-06 20:45:00
3  ghi  2020-08-05 21:30:00
4  jkl  2020-08-03 20:13:00
5  mno  2020-08-01 17:33:00
6  pqr  2020-07-29 19:19:19
```

So with that two tables, the result would have to be the number 3, as both tables have 05.08 - 07.08 in a row...

I hope you understand my case.

I found examples with ROWNUMBER to find gaps etc, however, its hard to combine it with both tables.

Can anybody help me out on how to do this with MySQL?

I also though about just collecting all the data in PHP and doing it there, however, when the data grows, it will be much more perfomant doing it with MySQL (database side), rather then doing it in PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there are 2 consecutive periods, 3 and 4 days long, what is desired output?

Comment: Specify precisely your DBMS and its version.

Comment: @Akina both tables have to have the streak, so if one table has a streak of 3 and the other of 4, then it would be 3. The thing would be to go back from the current day, check if the next entry is from last day in both tables, if not -> streak = 0, if yes, streak=1, then going to the next entry, checking both tables again, if entry in both table is from the day before -> streak = 2, otherwise streak=1, etc.

Comment: @Akina I'm using mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.45-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Comment: No. What if BOTH TABLES have the same consecutive period of 3 days and another (later or ealier) one more consecutive period of 4 days? What do you need in that case? greatest (4)? least (3)? sum (7)? the former/latter period length?

Comment: @Akina I always need the consecutive period, starting from today (or today-1 day).. So it doesn't mind, if the user had 100 entries in a row one time, whenever he does no entry any more, the counter is reset. It's always only the consecutive period until today.

Comment: I.e. if "today" is '2020-08-07' then the answer for above data  is `3`, but tomorrow it will be `0` if the row will be added into only one table or into none table? or desired answer become zero in a day after tomorrow? or after 2 days, week, month?

Comment: if tomorrow the user would not add an entry in the morning, the number will be 0

Answer (score 2):

Combine the tables using `union all` and aggregate to get days with *both*.  Then use the gaps-and-islands methods:

```
with me as (
      select dte
      from ((select date(timestamp) as dte, 1 as morning, 0 as evening
             from morning
            ) union all
            (select date(timestamp) as dte, 0 as morning, 1 as evening
             from evening
            )
           ) me
      group by dte
      having sum(morning) > 0 and sum(evening) > 0
     )
select min(dte), max(dte), count(*)
from (select dte, row_number() over (order by dte) as seqnum
      from me
     ) me
group by dte - interval seqnum day
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95cddfb0ff1f2dbc1fe75ee18d207b57) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

Actually, this is not particularly hard to adapt variables to this problem:

```
select min(dte), max(dte), count(*)
from (select dte, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from (select dte
            from ((select date(timestamp) as dte, 1 as morning, 0 as evening
                   from morning
                  ) union all
                  (select date(timestamp) as dte, 0 as morning, 1 as evening
                   from evening
                  )
                 ) me
            group by dte
            having sum(morning) > 0 and sum(evening) > 0
            order by dte
           ) d cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) me
group by dte - interval seqnum day
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: tried that just now. PHPMyAdmin is already throwing an error at the `with` as is seems...it seems like it doesn't know `with`.. any other way to do it?

Comment: also tried it in another program then PHPMyAdmin now to make sure its no problem of PMA, but it's not...

Comment: @nameless . . . (1) There is a db<>fiddle illustrating that this works.  (2) It requires MySQL 8+ or MariaDB 10.20.0 -- both of these were introduced multiple years ago.  I note that you mention "rownumber" in the question, implying that you are using a more recent version.

Comment: yes, I said I found solutions with ROWNUMBER, my version doesn't seem to have it available though.. As mentioned in comments above, updating to MariaDB 10.2 doesn't seem too easy, as there are some dependencies..So a solution for MariaDB 10.1 would be great

Comment: @nameless . . . Actually, it is not hard to adapt this solution for variables, which I added to the answer and the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the update, its working in general now, however, it doesn't behave exactly as I want it to behave.. As mentioned in the comments after my question, whenever there is one day, where user didn't add the entries, the value should be 0...  See the updated fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9fadc8d36ff8ff049abe9df8788a94d0

In that case, value should be 0, because the user diddn't add an entry on 06.08.2020 in the evening table...

Comment: any ideas what to change to get it working as expected? You can compare the behaviour to a login streak.. Every day, the user logs in, he gets 1 day in his streak.. Whenever, he doesn't login any more one day, the counter is reset to 0 and starts again - basically for me, the behaviour is the same, just that there need to be one entry in every table every day instead of a login every day

Comment: @nameless . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have a different question, please ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: No, as it doesn't work like I asked for.. I always said going back from today, maybe now I have just made it clear but what I explained is always what I wanted. There can't be a gap until "today" and with your solution, this doesn't mind.

Comment: As another example, take above data from my question.. If the user doesn't add an entry today in the morning, the streak will go to 0, as he missed adding and entry in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT DATE(m.`timestamp`) uni_date                              
          FROM morningTable m
          JOIN eveningTable e ON DATE(m.`timestamp`) = DATE(e.`timestamp`) ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT uni_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY uni_date DESC) rn
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE, uni_date ) + 1) output
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE, uni_date ) + 1
```

If tables contains too many rows then maybe it is safe to restrict the dates checked in `cte1` with some date value which is before the latter gap with guarantee.

PS. Sorry, this is available starting from MariaDB 10.2.1...

---

In MariaDB 10.1.45 the next query must work:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, MIN(uni_date)) + 1 output
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT DATE(m.`timestamp`) uni_date                              
       FROM morningTable m
       JOIN eveningTable e ON DATE(m.`timestamp`) = DATE(e.`timestamp`) ) t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT DATE(m.`timestamp`) uni_date                              
                          FROM morningTable m
                          JOIN eveningTable e ON DATE(m.`timestamp`) = DATE(e.`timestamp`) ) t2
                   WHERE t2.uni_date = t1.uni_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
  AND ( SELECT DATE(MAX(m.`timestamp`))
        FROM morningTable m
        JOIN eveningTable e ON DATE(m.`timestamp`) = DATE(e.`timestamp`) ) = CURRENT_DATE
```

If today has no row in at least one table the query will return NULL - you may use COALESCE for to obtain zero instead.

Comment: unfortunately "WITH" doesn't work in my version... Upgrade seems to be hard, just tried it.. Any alternatives to that?

Comment: any way to do this with 10.1?

Comment: thank you, maybe I will eventually be able to update, so far no success though...

Comment: tried with the alternative code.. interesting is, that it works in a db fiddle, but not in my project... I'm getting the result 8, where it should be 3...

Comment: do you have any ideas, why this could happen?

Comment: seems like the SQL has a problem, see this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9ac56635e4f600958f445b2e5ddd366a

in that case it should be 2 days, it shows 6 though...